# How to migrate widget from targetSdkVersion 25 to 26?

Tags: android, widget, android-pendingintent, android-8.0-oreo

After I updated the targetSdkVersion to 26 Widgets in my application stopped responding to clicks events.
I didn't find any solution on the web. it seems that only if we call PendingIntent.getActivity(...) it will work and open the app, but in my application, I need to make some background actions after the widget clicked.

I read about the [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background). But didn't get it how to make it work... so this is my code below

Manifest:

```
   <receiver android:name="com.test.widget.WidgetClock" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="enter" />

            <category android:name="enterAction" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_clock_provider" />
    </receiver>
```

AppWidgetProvider that extends AppWidgetProvider:

```
public class WidgetClock extends AppWidgetProvider{

    public  RemoteViews views;
    public Context context;


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        this.context = context;


        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            //start action method:
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_small_clock);
            Intent intent = new Intent("enterAction").addCategory("enterAction");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bEnter_Widget_small, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if ("enterAction".equals(action)) {
                //To something...
                update(context);
        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }


    public void update(Context context){
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), WidgetSmallClock.class.getName());
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
        onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

And this is how i refreshing the widget programmatically via MainActivity..

```
public static void updateWidget(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,WidgetClock.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, WidgetClock.class));
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

How can I migrate my existing code and make this action works?

Comment: You're using an implicit `Intent` for your `PendingIntent`; i.e., you're using an `Intent` that does not target a specific component. Those no longer work for manifest-registered Receivers, as of API level 26. Use an explicit `Intent` instead; e.g., `Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetClock.class);`. You can then remove the  `<intent-filter>` element (or parts thereof) for that action/category from the `<receiver>` element in the manifest.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks!